# Right relation for eloquent model

Tags: php, eloquent, relational-database, mysql-workbench, slim-3

After several attempts, I can not make an eloquent "relations" work.

I created a database with MySQL Workbech which contains the following tables:

- Actors
- ActorData
- Nationality

Their relationship image:

[image: relationship]

In PHP instead I have the following code (summary):

```
class ActorData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'actordata';

    [..]

    public function nationality()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Models\ActorData\Nationality");
    }
}

class Actor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'actors';

    [..]

    public function actorData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ActorData');
    }
}
```

My goal is, when i call "->nationality", i wish it takes the "nationality", but i recive "null" or errors about "keys" not found.

```
$actorData = \App\Models\Actor::find(1)->actorData()->first();
var_dump($actorData->nationality);
```

I understand that "hasOne" looks for the key in "nationality", but I wanted to make a simple "link".
As another solution, so I could simply take the "Nationality_Id" and look for it in the "Nationality" table, but I think it's a wrong approach.

I hope I have been exhaustive, thanks for your cooperation.

( in order to "fix" i had to add "$actorData->nationality()->associate($nationality))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You relationship should look something like the above.

Where actorData is a pivot table for the 2 other tables.

Your classes should look like this:

```
class Actors extends Model{
    public function nationality() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Nationality::class);
    }
}

class Nationality extends Model {
    public function actors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Actors::class);
    }
}
```

You're basically looking at [Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Where each actor can have many nationalities while at the same time each nationality can belong to many actors.

Normally laravel expects the pivot table to be named something like `actor_nationality`, but you can specify the table name:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(ModelClassGoesHere, 'PIVOT TABLE GOES HERE', 'FIRST TABLE ID', 'SECOND TABLE ID');
```

Comment: ow, i understand but.
This means that somehow actor is a "child" of nationality? tomorrow i'll try ur version :)

Comment: Is a many-to-many definitely correct?  A nationality may have many actors, but an actor should only have 1 nationality.

Comment: @JohnHalsey it should be something like "an actor have a nationality" only one, so nationality i don't know how it should be "related" :(

Comment: Well I mean people can have more than one nationality. But redefine it as you see fit.

Comment: each record of nationality is a "nationality", like at 1 we have "English", the it_IT means "Inglese" then the column en_US means "English", then i need to connect only one nationality to each actor, so when i call "$actor->nationality" i receave "1" if is english. i can achieve this using other methos, put i suppose is a best practices using relational database.. :(

Comment: I need to "play" with this, but i suppose this drive me in the right dir, so mark as right :) ty u all

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you put the `nationality_id` directly on the `actors` table since, they can only have one.  Then your relationship on the `Actor` would be

```
public function nationality() {
    return $this->hasOne(Nationality::class);
}
```

Then you could do `$actor->nationality;`

Your nationality class would be...

```
class Nationality extends Model {
    public function actors() {
        return $this->hasMany(Actor::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i know, that's is what i suppose to do, but only errors.
It's like eloquent, expect to do other things. It has a strange behaviour.. but that way doesn't work. Dunno why